# Refactor to reduce code duplication

Tags: scala

I have four methods like these (here are only two of them):

```
  def checkLeft(clickedIndex: Int): Option[Int] = {
    val leftIndex = clickedIndex - 1
    if (leftIndex >= 0 && clickedIndex % field.width != 0 && isEmptyCell(leftIndex))
      Some(leftIndex)
    else
      None
  }

  def checkRight(clickedIndex: Int): Option[Int] = {
    val rightIndex = clickedIndex + 1
    if (rightIndex < field.size && clickedIndex + 1 % field.width != 0 && isEmptyCell(rightIndex))
      Some(rightIndex)
    else
      None
  }
```

They all have similar structures. How I can reduce code duplication here?

Comment: Does `bottomIndex` depend on `clickedIndex`? And what `something1` depends on?

Comment: @PetrPudlák I edited question with real code. Please review it

Comment: Pretty sure in the second block you'll want parens around `clickedIndex + 1` before the % operator.

Answer (score 2):

For the LEFT case, you're checking that an index is above the low value of zero; for the RIGHT case, you're checking that it's below the high value of field.size.  You can't really reconcile these except by combining them into a method that checks both boundaries - and there's nothing wrong with that.  Now you've got

```
if (inBounds(theIndex) && isEmptyCell(theIndex) && ...)
    Some(theIndex)
```

That ... is questionable to me because you seem to be comparing a different index (clickedIndex or clickedIndex + 1) depending on LEFT or RIGHT.

I think there are errors here that you need to reconcile before going too far down the path of duplication elimination.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be with a trait or abstract class defining the basic behaviour of a check.  Then you extend that for the actual checks you want.

```
trait indexCheck {
  def adjustedIndex( index: Int): Int = index
  def newIndexCondition(index: Int): Boolean = true
  def oldIndexCondition(index: Int): Boolean = true
  def apply( clickedIndex: Int): Option[Int] = {
    val returnIndex = adjustedIndex(clickedIndex)
    if (newIndexCondition(returnIndex) && oldIndexCondition(clickedIndex) && isEmptyCell(returnIndex))
      Some(returnIndex)
    else None
  }
}
```

Then you create checkLeft and checkRight classes, overriding methods as necessary

```
class checkLeft extends indexCheck {
  override def adjustedIndex(index: Int): Int = index - 1
  override def newIndexCondition(index: Int): Boolean = {
     index >= 0
  }
  override def oldIndexCondition(index: Int): Boolean = {
      index % field.width != 0
  }
}

aCheck = new checkLeft
aCheck(clickedIndex) // The magic apply method is used here.
```

My example above is probably a little over-specific.  It would be more flexible just to have a conditionList onto which could be pushed a sequence of functions returning booleans.  But you get the idea.

By the way, I used traits in case you wanted to be able to create classes which did radically different things but also implemented checks.  However, if you made **indexCheck** a class rather than a trait, you could do things like building maps of anonymous classes, like this:

```
val checks:Map[String,indexCheck] = Map(
  "left" -> new indexCheck {
    override def adjustedIndex(index: Int): Int = index - 1
    override def newIndexCondition(index: Int): Boolean = {
      index >= 0
    }
    override def oldIndexCondition(index: Int): Boolean = {
      index % field.width != 0
    }
  },
  "right" -> new indexCheck {
    override def adjustedIndex(index: Int): Int = index + 1
    override def newIndexCondition(index: Int): Boolean = {
      index < field.size
    }
    override def oldIndexCondition(index: Int): Boolean = {
      Index + 1 % field.width != 0
    }
  }
)
```

Which gives you a map of anonymous classes, which you can use like this:

```
checks("left")(SomeValue)
checks("right")(SomeOtherValue)
```

or whatever.

Another way to do this would be through higher order functions.  That is, methods can return functions just like any other value/object.  So you could have a method that took various parameters (some of them would have to be closures) and returned a function that would implement a specific check - a check factory, if you like.  I'd need to know more about the parent object to give a useful demo of that.